# Get Location for Ip address C#, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am using this code to retrieve the users location based on the IP address. It doesnt return any location, countrycode...All the columns in the datatable are blank except the IP
[image]

```
string i = "aa.b.23.58";
            DataTable dt = GetLocation(i.Trim());
     public DataTable GetLocation(string strIPAddress)
        {
            //Create a WebRequest with the current Ip
        WebRequest _objWebRequest =
            WebRequest.Create("http://freegeoip.appspot.com/xml/"  +strIPAddress);


        //Create a Web Proxy
        WebProxy _objWebProxy =
           new WebProxy("http://freegeoip.appspot.com/xml/"
                     + strIPAddress, true);

        //Assign the proxy to the WebRequest
        _objWebRequest.Proxy = _objWebProxy;

        //Set the timeout in Seconds for the WebRequest
        _objWebRequest.Timeout = 2000;

        try
        {
            //Get the WebResponse 
            WebResponse _objWebResponse = _objWebRequest.GetResponse();
            //Read the Response in a XMLTextReader
            XmlTextReader _objXmlTextReader
                = new XmlTextReader(_objWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

            //Create a new DataSet
            DataSet _objDataSet = new DataSet();
            //Read the Response into the DataSet
            _objDataSet.ReadXml(_objXmlTextReader);

            return _objDataSet.Tables[0];
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    } // End of GetLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

try this sample
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3265/GeoIP-Where-are-your-internet-visitors-coming-from

probably you have some problems with freegeoip.appspot.com

you can keep the ip to location db in your project.